# How to display data inside longlistselector in windowsphone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a webservice in which, json data is in the following format. What i need to do is, "List Category" should get binded to groupheader and also to jump header list. And "List MenuItem" to ItemTemplate. I have designed datatemplates in xaml. But not sure of how to do this task?

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Menuitemid { get; set; }
    public int Menucategoryid { get; set; }
    public string Itemname { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }       
}

public class Category
{
    public int Menucategoryid { get; set; }
    public int Menuid { get; set; }
    public string Categoryname { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }      
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Menuid { get; set; }
    public int Appid { get; set; }
    public string Menuname { get; set; }
    public string Menudescription { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Menuguid { get; set; }           
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample LongListSelector Demo : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/LongListSelector-Demo-45364cc9

helpful links :

[Implementing LongListSelector as JumpLists in Windows Phone 8 : Alphabetical List](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/06/18/implementing-longlistselector-as-jumplists-in-windows-phone-8-alphabetical-list.aspx)

[Displaying data in flat list in Windows Phone 8 LongListSelector Control](http://abundantcode.com/displaying-data-in-flat-list-in-windows-phone-8-longlistselector-control/)

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/23/windows-phone-8-xaml-longlistselector.aspx

Comment: hi Ouadie, i have verified these links. can u pls write code according to my requirement?

Comment: Hi, just start with this sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093 All you need to do is replace Data.